# calling a php file in another php file jquery elevatezoom doesnt work

Tags: php, jquery

I am a beginner so please bear with me.

I am using `jquery.elevatezoom.js` to zoom on images.

It is working fine, but the problem is when I name this file say `showimage.php` in my `dashboard.php` using PHP's include function, the jquery function defined in `showimage.php` is not executing, thus I am not getting the zoom.

I have a dashboard. When I click on a button, it is bound to a JavaScript function that loads the  page in the dashboard, and the page getting loaded is a PHP file that includes `showimage.php`.

1. `Jquery.min` is called at the dashboard's load event.
2. The dashboard has a button that when clicked loads a php file that first loads 
   `showimage.php` using php's include function.

Here is the code for `showimage.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <title>jQuery elevateZoom Demo</title>
    <script src='jquery.elevatezoom.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Basic Zoom Example</h1>
<img id="zoom_01" src='images/large/image1.jpg' width="250px" height="250px"  data-zoom-image="images/large/image1.jpg"/>
<br />
<script>
    $('#zoom_01').elevateZoom({easing : true}); 
</script>
</body>
</html>

details.php
<?PHP
include 'showimage.php';
?>
```

Can anyone help me determine why zoom isn't working?

Comment: So... what it doesn't do? o_o

Comment: it is not executing the <script>
    $('#zoom_01').elevateZoom({easing : true}); 
</script>.

Comment: put in inside document ready or function(){}

Comment: i tried to put it in dashboard's document ready funciton but it is not working.

Comment: can you show us  showimage.php code?

Comment: and what's with details.php? and why are you including stuff after </html>?

Comment: the first code fragment is from showimage.php

Comment: sir the second code is from details.php both the fragments are different...

Comment: do you load details.php through ajax or something?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the script is executing before the html finish to add the element , so you could try to call it after a few seconds, something like this in your showimage.php file.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

   setTimeout(function(){

      $('#zoom_01').elevateZoom({easing : true});

   }, 3000);

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use on ready event and make your jquery call like that:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#zoom_01').elevateZoom({easing : true}); 
});
```

and put javascript after included php files.

BTW I don't see included jquery library on your document?

Answer (score 0):

try using it only when the document is ready. You have already included jquery so do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // you move it to here so only when your page is done loading it will add the event handler
    $('#zoom_01').elevateZoom({easing : true});
})
```